# How to exclude a default component from _app.js from rendering in the slug

Tags: next.js

I have read through the documentations of Next.Js and I understood that by creating a _app.js file it will override the default App.js file, So those component in the _app.js file will show on every page and that's what I need, But I also need to exclude some of those components from rendering in the slug, Like the Header or Footer for example I wanna show them on all pages except for the slug, How can I do that ?

here is my code for the _app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Header from '@/components/Header/Header'
import theme from '@/theme/theme';


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

return (
  <Head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  </Head>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Header />
    <main>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  </ThemeProvider>
 )
}
```

And this is my slug

```
import React from 'react'

 const MyAccounts = ({ data }) => {

const post = data && data.posts[0]
return (
      <>
        <div>
            <article>
                {post.feature_image ?
                    <figure >
                        <img src={post.feature_image} alt={post.title} />
                    </figure> : null}
                <section >
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                </section>
            </article>
        </div>
        </>
)
}


 export default MyAccounts
```

So in this Code I dont want the component Head to show in my slug, How do I exclude it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `_app.js` you have the `pageProps`, you can leverage that. Set some property in it and render based on that.

Something like:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

return (
  <Head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  </Head>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {pageProps.noLayout ? <></> : <Header />}
    <main>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  </ThemeProvider>
 )
}
```

and then on the page add for example:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: { noLayout: true },
  }
}
```